# How to download multiple envelops from the docusign

Tags: php, docusignapi

We have integrated DocuSign into our application and users are filling all the info and completing the docusign process. Also, we have implemented the functionality using docusign soap API to download envelop that status completed.

But now we want to download all the envelops that are completed. Is there any REST API or Soap API in php to download bulk envelops at a time. If yes please provide the details with examples.

Thanks,
Srinivas Reddy .A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations on your integration successes!

Do you want to download envelope information or the documents from the envelopers?

**Use Connect**

The usual technique for integrating completed envelope transactions and documents into existing systems is to use some form of the Connect feature. Connect enables you to establish a web hook, a listener, that is called by the DocuSign platform when envelopes or individual signature requests have reached a particular status level.

When you make an Envelope request through the API, you can include a call back "Connect" url as part of the request. See the [eventNotification parameter](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definition-eventNotification)

You can also establish a Connect listener at the account level instead of including the data with each envelope creation. Your Connect listener can be configured via the [API](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Set%20Up%20a%20Connect%20Configuration.htm) or via the Preferences section of the Classic DocuSign Web App.

[Message content documentation](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/connect-guide.pdf) when your web hook listener is called by Connect

Another idea is to use the [Retrieve product](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/retrieve-quick-start-guide.pdf). It downloads completed envelopers and signed documents for you, to a windows server. You can then use local processes to store the data and completed documents.

**Documents from envelopes**

The API method [Get Document from Envelope](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Document%20from%20Envelope.htm) enables you to retrieve a specific document from an envelope.

[Get Envelope Documents and Certificate](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Documents%20and%20Certificate.htm) enables you to retrieve all of the documents.

For both of these, you'd need to first loop through your envelopes to find the ones with the completed status.

Comment: Thanks Larry. Actually we want to download documents from envelops that are completed. We want to download all the envelop documents for a template in zip format. The above process works for this? Please confirm.

Comment: Connect will *deliver* the envelopes' documents to you. You don't download anything, your webhook url is called by the Connect service. Please ask a second, separate question if you have more questions about how Connect works.

Comment: @user2696525 what Larry is saying is that you'll need a listener on a web server that waits for a POST from docusign. The body of the POST contains your documents, which you can then upload to another service (we're using S3), or save on your server.

Comment: Thanks Larry and Dave, Is this work always when we need to download the documents. So when ever I clicked on the download link it will trigger a  code to download the documents (Listener on a web server). If it works then please provide the steps for  listener on a web server.

Comment: Hi Larry/Dave, Can you please respond on this. Thanks

Comment: With Connect, there is no download link. Instead, DocuSign calls your sw. Based on your questions, I suggest that you investigate the Retrieve product. It downloads documents for you to your own system.